# How to target an element in html which is the first child visible?

Tags: css

This code is going to be used to overload the style of a page I dont control. I cannot change the HTML nor can I use JavaScript. I can only rely on good old CSS. The HTML is dynamic and look like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" style="display: none">m</div>
    <div class="item">n</div>
    <div class="item">o</div>
    <div class="item">p</div>
</div>
```

I dont know how many children `.container` have. No `nth-child()` as far as I am aware of. The following example is valid too:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" style="display: none">l</div>
    <div class="item" style="display: none">m</div>
    <div class="item">n</div>
    <div class="item">o</div>
    <div class="item">p</div>
</div>
```

I want to apply a specific property to the first visible element. Here it is 'n'.

If all element are red:

```
.item {
  background: red;
}
```

I would like to change it to blue:

```
??? {
  background: blue;
}
```

I tried:

```
.item {
  background: red;
}

.item:not([style='display: none']):first-child {
  background: blue;
}
```

Demo:

```css
.item {
  background: red;
}

.item:not([style='display: none']):first-child {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item" style="display: none">m</div>
        <div class="item">n</div>
        <div class="item">o</div>
        <div class="item">p</div>
    </div>
```

Here 'n' should have a blue background.

How can I achieve that? What selector should I use?

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr (explanation followings):

```
.item[style='display: none'] + .item:not([style='display: none']) {
  background: blue;
}
```

---

Alright, first we can achieve this by rethinking the problem. Asking for the first visible child is actually the same logic as asking the **first child after** the **last hidden child**.

CSS have some uncommon combinator. Here we are going to use the adjacent sibling combinator (`+`). Let the [MSDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) introduce it:

> The **adjacent sibling combinator** (`+`) separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it *immediately* follows the first element, and both are children of the same parent element.

```
/* Paragraphs that come immediately after any image */
img + p {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

We can color every hidden `.item` following another hidden `.item` like that:

```
.item[style='display: none'] + .item[style='display: none'] {
  background: blue;
}
```

But what we want is the **first child after** the **last hidden child**. Here the pseudo-attribute `:not()` will do the trick:

```
.item[style='display: none'] + .item:not([style='display: none']) {
  background: blue;
}
```

Demo:

```css
.item {
  background: red;
}

.item[style='display: none'] + .item:not([style='display: none']) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" style="display: none">l</div>
    <div class="item" style="display: none">m</div>
    <div class="item">n</div>
    <div class="item">o</div>
    <div class="item">p</div>
</div>
```